# Animating a div by width using a jquery variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to take the value from the division of two jquery variables and use it to change the width of a div. 
I think the problem is here `animate({width:'"+percent+"%'});`

here is the jquery:

```
var x = 56;
var y = 64
var percent = Math.ceil((x/y)*100);
$(".box").animate({width:'"+percent+"%'});
```

here is the html:

```
<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: Why are you putting quotes inside the string? That's just like doing this in your CSS: `width: "90"%`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var x = 56;
var y = 64
var percent = Math.ceil((x/y)*100);
$(".box").animate({width: percent + "%"});
```

Here is jsFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/Bz4hC/1/

Answer (score 2):

Your string concatenation is the problem, just do

```
$(".box").animate({
    width: percent + '%'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var x = 56; var y = 64: var percent = Math.ceil((x/y)*100);
```

percent  will always be 100%